# "TypeError: undefined is not a function" when calling a function from the factory

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to call a function defined in the factory via controller, but getting an error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function.

Could someone help please help me?

```
//service
angular.module('Blog').factory('postData', function($http) {
  var postData = {}
  postData.data.posts = [{
    title: 'first title',
    contents: 'first contents'
  }]
  postData.loadPosts = function() {
    postData.data.posts = $http.get('./posts.json')
      .success(function(data) {
        postData.data.posts = data;
      })
      .error(function() {
        console.error('Failed loading data');
      })
  }
  postData.createPost = function(newPost) {
    var data;
    if (newPost.newPostTitle === '' || newPost.newPostContents === '') {
      alert('Neither the Title nor the Body are allowed to be left blank.');
      return false;
    }
    data = {
      new_post: {
        title: newPost.newPostTitle,
        contents: newPost.newPostContents
      }
    };
    $http.post('./posts.json', data).success(function(data) {
      postData.data.posts.push(data);
      console.log('Successfully created post.');
    }).error(function() {
      console.error('Failed to create new post.');
    });
    return true;
  };

  console.log("initialized postdata");
  return postData;
})


//controller
var createPostCtrl = function($scope, $location, postData) {
  postData = postData;
  $scope.data = postData.data;
  postData.loadPosts();
  $scope.formData = {
    newPostTitle: '',
    newPostContents: ''
  };


  $scope.createPost = function() {
    // This one is throwing an error TypeError: undefined is not a function
    postData.createPost($scope.formData)
  };
};
```

Comment: It looks like you should also do `var postData = { data: {} };`, otherwise the next line will fail because `postData.data` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

module function need dependency as second argument. If no dependency you can write:

```
angular.module('Blog', [])
```

Comment: Further info: if you call `angular.module()` with only one string parameter, it will return you either an existing module with that name, or `undefined`. If you aren't declaring the `Blog` module elsewhere using the version with 2 parameters, that is why `angular.module('Blog')` would be returning undefined.