# Now I have error "ReferenceError: items is not defined" and cannot ideas how I can test my dataService.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocking, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I need help, about added jasmine tast to my factory.
 My code is...

---dataService.js---

```
angular.module('angularAppApp')
   .factory('dataService', function($resource){
      return $resource(`http://...:3100/posts/:id`, null,
         {
           'update': { method:'PUT' }
      });
})
```

---onePostCtrl.js ---

```
angular.module('angularAppApp')
   .controller('onePostCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 'dataService',
     function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, dataService) {
         dataService.get ({id: $routeParams.postId}).$promise.then(function(data){
             $scope.postInfo = data;
         });
       }]);
```

-- main container ---

```
angular.module('angularAppApp').controller('postCtrl', ['$scope','$http', 'ngDialog', 'dataService','trimService', function ($scope, $http, ngDialog, dataService, trimService) {
//save data to remote server from loaded pop-up
$scope.savePost = function(){
 $scope.addFormData.date = $scope.formated_date;
      dataService.save($scope.addFormData, function() {
            laodData();
      });
      ngDialog.closeAll();
};
//delete post from remote server
$scope.deletePost = function(article) {
      dataService.delete({ id:  article._id }, function() {
            laodData();
  });
};
//edit post from remote server
$scope.updatePost = function (article) {
     dataService.update({ id:  article._id},article).$promise.then(function() {
            laodData();
      });
      ngDialog.closeAll();
}
```

}]);

--- mock data ---

```
angular.module('mock', []).value('items', [{ ... }]
```

---At index.html I am have loaded mocks scripts---

```
 src="bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"
 src="mosk_data/mocks.module.js"
```

--Jasmine tests is ...

```
describe("factory of dataService", function (){  
 var $httpBackend, $http, $q, factory;
  beforeEach(module("angularAppApp"));
  beforeEach(module('mock'));
    beforeEach(function(){

     inject(function($injector, _$httpBackend_,_$http_,_$q_){
       $q = _$q_;
       $http = _$http_;
       $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
       $httpBackend.when('GET', '/items').respond(items);
       factory = $injector.get('dataService');
    });
afterEach(function () {
     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
 });
it("Data service", function(){
});
```

});

Now, I have error "ReferenceError: items is not defined" and cannot ideas how I can test my dataService.

Comment: See this, I believe the issue cause is same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835529/angularjs-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function/26835597#26835597

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to inject your value and assign it to a variable in the tests. Try this:

```
var $httpBackend, $http, $q, factory, items; //declare variable items here (or you can do it inside beforeEach)
  beforeEach(module("angularAppApp"));
  beforeEach(module('mock'));
    beforeEach(function(){

     inject(function($injector, _$httpBackend_,_$http_,_$q_, _items_){
       $q = _$q_;
       $http = _$http_;
       //inject the value and assign to your variable
       items = _items_
       $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
       $httpBackend.when('GET', '/items').respond(items);
       factory = $injector.get('dataService');
    });
```

The `Reference error` you got was because there was no *variable* called `items`. You defined an *angular value* with name `items`, but it's not the same as a variable - think of it as it lives "somewhere inside angular guts" and to use it you have to inject it and then use as normal variable.

Comment: Great thanks!! Now I have no Reference error and mock data have called.

Comment: One more question, I cannot search information how test
my factory which using mock data instead $resource(`http://...:3100/posts/:id`, null...)

Comment: If you want to test `$resource` just use `$httpBackend` and type the full URL you expect it to call.

Comment: Yes, I have test  connection to server $httpBackend.expectGET('http://54.72.3.96:3000/posts/').respond(200, 'server data'); But I have no ideas how can test my factory dataService and postCtrl controllers methods savePost, deletePost, updatePost using mock data.

Comment: You hahve `respond` function, which you define what will response look like - use your mock data as an argument of this function. Everything is described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)